# How to find out page layout value in an event receiver for publishing page

Tags: event-receivers

I need to find out page layout on ItemUpdated from the SPItemEventProperties in a page library. What property value should I be looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't it isn't available, look at ItemUpdating and treat it as ItemUpdated.

Do this with

```
SPListItem.SystemUpdate()
```

As it doesn't fire off updated.

Then layout is in

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PageLayout.Name;

PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(SPContext.Current.Web);
SPFile file = SPContext.Current.File;
Guid guid = file.UniqueId;
PublishingPage publishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(publishingPages[id].ListItem);
string pageName = publishingPage.Layout.Name;
```

Comment: I figured it out SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;  item.properties["PublishingPageLayout"] provides the value.

Comment: Can you post it as your answer please when it is ready. It isn't listed as being in there on msdn, but I did look :P

Answer (score 0):

I would presume your talking about this?

http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/spitemeventproperties-itemupdated.html

if its through code then you need to make an event reciver and have this:

```
public override void  ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties) 
{     
      base.ItemUpdating(properties); 
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713708(v=office.12).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties_properties.aspx

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I figured it out     SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;                  string pageLayout =item.properties["PublishingPageLayout"].ToString();                  provides the value.